# strsplit in R not working for $ as split character

Tags: r, strsplit

```
> str = "a$b$c"
> astr <- strsplit(str,"$")
> astr
[[1]]
[1] "a$b$c"
```

Still trying to figure the answer out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape it

```
strsplit(str,"\\$")
```

Comment: no rather, strsplit(str,"[$]")

Comment: I just figured it out myself. it is well described in ?strsplit in R. My bad :(

Comment: @user3356424 good! The `[` escape I believe is that one used in SQL Server for wildcards escape, like `where col like '%50[%]%'`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use , `fixed = TRUE` option:

```
strsplit(str,"$",fixed=TRUE) 
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
```